# Call react component and functions from external js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, external

i'm making a chrome extension for a specific website. This site is made with react. I need to call some functions / variables that are inside some components.

How can i made this from a totally external .js?

This is what i tried

```
ReactDOM.render(<Page ref={(ourComponent) => {window.ourComponent = ourComponent}} />, document.getElementById("app"));
ReactDOM.render(<Page ref={(ourComponent) => {window.ourComponent = ourComponent}} >, document.getElementById("app"));
```

But throw me:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Comment: That's JSX syntax, which isn't supported in any browser by default. You'd have to change it to the appropriate `React.createElement` function call.

Comment: from what i understood you have an encapsulated function component that have his own state / methods that changes in this state and you want another component to use those methods to do the same effect , so if so you can use a hook called " useImperativeHandle" and this youtube video explain it  very easy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8PwptJ6Qlk&ab_channel=JoeMaddalone

Comment: @Julia do you mean to create a component that extends the component that i need to have access to? Can you give me an example?